# rsync duplicates files when archiving to another computer when using include-from

Tags: bash, rsync

#### Background:

I got a new computer and am trying to use rsync to copy files over to it (Apple's migration assistant repeatedly gets to 16 min left and then hangs forever--I'm trying to work around that problem by using rsync).

#### Problem:

I'm trying to copy files from my old computer over to my new one. I'm running the following script on my new computer.

```
# in Dropbox/migrate.sh:
set -x

IP=10.1.1.5
rsync -navzhe ssh --include-from="Dropbox/migration_files.txt" --exclude="*" $IP:.* ~



# in Dropbox/migration_files.txt:
.lein/
.lein/profiles.clj
bmaddy/
bmaddy/4clojure.clj
Desktop**
```

#### Expected:

I expect to see something like this:

```
$ Dropbox/migrate.sh 
++ IP=10.1.1.5
++ rsync -navzhe ssh --include-from=Dropbox/migration_files.txt '--exclude=*' '10.1.1.5:.*' /Users/bmaddy
receiving file list ... done
./
.lein/
.lein/profiles.clj
Desktop/
Desktop/piano.txt
bmaddy/
bmaddy/4clojure.clj
```

#### Actual:

What I actually see is this:

```
$ Dropbox/migrate.sh 
++ IP=10.1.1.5
++ rsync -navzhe ssh --include-from=Dropbox/migration_files.txt '--exclude=*' '10.1.1.5:.*' /Users/bmaddy
receiving file list ... done
./
.lein/
.lein/profiles.clj
Desktop/
Desktop/piano.txt
bmaddy/
bmaddy/4clojure.clj
bmaddy/.lein/
bmaddy/.lein/profiles.clj
bmaddy/Desktop/
bmaddy/Desktop/piano.txt
bmaddy/bmaddy/
bmaddy/bmaddy/4clojure.clj
```

When I actually run this (without -n), all the files in `Desktop`, `.lein`, and `bmaddy` get duplicated under the `bmaddy` directory.

Does anyone know why those files would be duplicated and how I could stop that from happening?

```
$ rsync --version
rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I found to eventually get things to work:

```
# in Dropbox/migrate.sh
set -x

IP=10.1.1.5

rsync -navzhe ssh --include-from="Dropbox/migration_files.txt" --exclude="*" $IP:. ~

# in Dropbox/migration_fiels.txt
/.lein/
/.lein/profiles.clj
/bmaddy/
/bmaddy/4clojure.clj
/Desktop**
```